# How download base64 data as image?

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, base64, digital-signature

I use vue-signature Library and I Don't know how to download base64 data generated as image,
Here is Link of library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-signature
I've already read the documentation and see That "Save()" Methods Save image as PNG/JPG… but it give me base64 data,
thank you for your collaboration, I use vue js

Comment: if you have the base64 data, you can turn it into a data-uri by pre-pending `data:image/png;base64,` which you can then display in an `<img>` tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not the most optimized solution, But it works.

```
var a = document.createElement("a"); //Create <a>
a.href = "data:image/png;base64," + ImageBase64; //Image Base64 Goes here
a.download = "Image.png"; //File name Here
a.click(); //Downloaded file
```

In your case you can try this

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);

// Returns signature image as data URL (see https://mdn.io/todataurl for the list of possible parameters)
signaturePad.toDataURL("image/jpeg"); // save image as JPEG
```

source : https://vuejsexamples.com/vue-signature-pad-component/

Comment: I try something like this `import SignaturePad from "signature_pad"... methods : { save(){ var canvas = document.querySelector("#signature");  var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas); signaturePad.toDataURL } } ` and he give me error like "canvas.getContext is not function"

Comment: Upvoted because I actually thought I had to convert the base64 to a blob then to a file, and only then you could actually download it. With your answer I realized you can skip all that process and download it directly as a base64 string.